# what is the openstack horizon dashboard default password

Tags: openstack

I have installed openstack on Ubuntu 14.

I have 2 questions:

First of all, horizon interface is listening on a virtual private interface (https://10.0.x.y/horizon). I have tried to put an iptable rule in order to access from outside:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j  DNAT --to-destination  10.0. x.y
```

But it does not work.

What is the default password for the /horizon http interface?

I have tried to login with lynx app directly on the server, but i got a 403 error...

I have defined a password on openstack-install (single mode), but i do not know the login (I have tried admin and ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The installer puts the password in the `user_secrets.yml` file:

[image]

In `/etc/openstack_deploy/user_secrets.yml` you will get all secrets but for OpenStack admin use:

```
sudo grep admin_pass /etc/openstack_deploy/user_secrets.yml
```

Once you get into Horizon you can change the admin password to something easier to remember!

**Note-:** This will work if OSA deployment is used.

**For MicroStack based OpenStack setup**

The installer puts the password in the `/var/snap/microstack/common/etc/microstack.rc`

[image]

You can probably fix the microstack command line tools by running:

```
sudo snap set microstack config.credentials.keystone-password=<your password>
```

That will prompt MicroStack to overwrite the default password in its .rc with the new password.

You can then do a comparison between `/var/snap/microstack/common/etc/microstack.rc` and the rc you downloaded, and file any missing pieces in the downloaded rc as a bug against MicroStack.

Answer (score 0):

Horizon doesn't have a default password, per se.  The admin password will be the password of a Keystone identity that has one of the roles that the Horizon configs designate as administrators for Horizon.  The default Horizon administrator role is "admin" but Horizon's "OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_ADMIN_ROLES" config attribute can be used to alter that.

If you installed using devstack then the "devstack/local.conf" file will contain the admin password that you specified when setting up.  I think the password defaults to admin ... if you were daft enough to not set one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kolla for deployment then file /etc/kolla/admin-open.sh and values:
OS_USERNAME and OS_PASSWORD will allow you to log in to Horizon